# Routing to a section ABC of page X from page Y from nav

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

all pages have same nav bar - nav is in header component.
page x,page Y are components

so far,i have tried :

1. nav's **link** to="" (With hash as well)
2. by including a function in link with **onclick**

p.s let me know if i need to mention more regarding the question.

Comment: Please provide more information on the structure of the code, what libraries are you using for routing and how exactly your routing code looks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out React-Router for adding routing in React applications.

Link: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Or, if you're already using this library in your code, then what is the error that you're getting?

Cheers!